# How to display the some content under selected value inside dropdown in angular2 application?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular2-routing, typescript2.0

I had developed angular 2 application with left nav bar having dropdown. But I want the functionality like whenever I select the value inside the dropdown of nav bar, it displays some list of links under the selected drop down value only.

This is the code I write to display the dropdown inside the nav bar:

```
<li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>---->if I select Action from Drop Down menu then some list of links displayed under the selected value only related to Action value. 
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

This is the image for the functionality I want in angular 2 application:

[image]

So, can anyone suggest me how to write the code for above functionality in angular 2 application?

Comment: You know, this is not a free code writing service ;) Present your code and show us where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Material Design you can do the following:

```
 <md-select placeholder="Something" [(ngModel)]="YourModel" name="something" required>
      <md-option *ngFor="let item of menuItems" [value]="item.value">{{item.text}}</md-option>
 </md-select>
```

Inside the component you have to create the array of menu items (menuItems) with text and values that you want to display.